# How to retrieve already shorted URLs from Bitly API

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have thousands of Long URLs that were shortened with the Bitly API.
I know wish to store those shortened URLS in a database.
Does any one knows how to retrieve the already shortened Bitly URL from a long URL?

Comment: What is stopping you from updating your whole url database (not by hand of course)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you got the short URL in the first place.

bit.ly should give you the same shortened URL back every time for the same URL passed in.

Comment: The URLs are sometimes different when a long URL is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass in the long url and get the info, you can use : /v3/link/lookup (http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_user_link_lookup)

If you need the long url based on shortened, then use the API with /v3/expand, this takes the params shortUrl and hash (http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_expand)

Comment: I think I actually need https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/user/ however I have an API Key and login and the instructions on how to format the URL is not so clear http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html#apikey